# upload large files in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to upload large files to my server (max 100mb files)

```
memory_limit = 30M
post_max_size = 192M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M 
max_execution_time = 7200 sec
max_input_time = 7200 sec
```

these are my server details i am using apache 2.2.21 so i change LimitRequestBody to upload folders support 2GB when i upload 80 mb file it will fail to upload when i upload 10 mb files successfully upload so any idea to upload large

Thanks for advance

Comment: try by increasing memory_limit, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize limit

Comment: If it's a shared hosting, it takes some time for this to take effect. If you own the server, try restarting your php and apache service and check

Comment: yes..i increase post_max_size to 50M and post_max_size and upload_max_filesize max size 192M

Comment: hi dkulkarni:i restart apache after changes but how can i restart php i am using virtual server

Comment: @user816891 You don't need to restart php :)

Comment: try coding using a keyboard with working punctation?

Comment: ...and look at your error logs to see why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If uploading do “logged-in” people, you should also check [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

Comment: my session.gc_maxlifetime is local value:1440 Master Value:1440

Answer (score 0):

**To upload a large file ( >5MB), I use the chuck upload method.**

```
/**
 * @param $file
 * @param $fileSize
 * @param $name
 * @return int
 */
public function chunkUpload($file, $fileSize, $name) {
    
    $targetFile     = 'upload/'. $name;
    $chunkSize      = 256; // chunk in bytes
    $uploadStart    = 0;

    $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
    $fp     = fopen($targetFile, 'w');

    # Start uploading
    try {
    
        while($uploadStart < $fileSize) {
        
            $contents = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
            fwrite($fp, $contents);
        
            $uploadStart += strlen($contents);
            fseek($handle, $uploadStart);
        }
    
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($fp);
        
        return 200;
        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 400;
    }
}
```